# xslt syntax error <text> element

Tags: xslt

This is what I am trying to do =

```
<xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//Row_3/YEAR"/></xsl:text>
```

And this is the error I get -

cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element 'xsl:text' must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like the error message says, `xsl:text` can't have any children. Just use the `<xsl:value-of select="//Row_3/YEAR"/>`.

Comment: But it worked before this. I just moved my workspace to a new computer and I this error started showing up. I have like 55 different places which have similar syntax. Thoughts?

Comment: @Return0 did your xslt version or parser change? Regardless of that, this does answer the question you asked. Please consider posting a separate question.

Comment: @Return0 - If you didn't have errors before, the XSLT wasn't getting validated at all. The good news is that XSLT is still XML, so you can write another transform to pull the nested `xsl:value-of`'s out of the `xsl:text`'s.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need the <xsl:text> for? According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_text.asp) this element may only contain *literal text, entity references, and #PCDATA*.

If there isn't a good reason for your construct try

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Row_3/YEAR"/>
```

instead.

Comment: Here's a link a little more reliable than W3Schools: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Text